# Вопрос по аллокатору C++

Tags: память, c++

Допустим, есть некая программа, назовем ее просмотрщик картинок, которая для размещения картинок в памяти использует предоставляемый системой heap.

Пользователь загружает в программу череду картинок размером по 4 Кb каждая, пока не исчерпывается весь heap.

Затем пользователь удаляет пару картинок из несмежных областей памяти, высвобождая тем самым объем памяти, равный 16 Kb (он удалил 4 картинки).

Вопрос, сможет ли он после произведенных операций, загрузить в программу картинку размером 16 Kb?

Comment: @SoloMio, еще до того, как закончится память в Heap у Вас начнутся серьезные проблемы с быстродействием (paging...).

Так что подумайте об оптимальном  размещении части картинок на диске, начиная с некоторого их объема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Даже если он поудаляет половину картинок, но только с четными номерами, то скорее всего не сможет выделить память под 8 кб картинку.

Ответ - с большой вероятностью что не сможет. Если только структура, которая хранит картинки не умеет размещаться в нескольких областях.

Comment: А есть ли такой умный C++ аллокатор, который сможет "нарезать" большой объект и разместить его в этих несмежных областях?

Comment: блочками по 4 кб? такими мелкими - врядли. На самом то деле операционная система делает что то подобное - там есть страницы памяти по несколько мегабайт, которые она может тасовать.

А с 4-8 кб - это нужно будет ещё как то с указателями разобраться. Массивы идут лесом, а векторы придется делать с нарушением стандарта - они ведь должны размещаться в непрерывной области памяти.

Но я знаю, что люди делают свои "хипы", которые хранят объекты, могут делать "утряску".

Comment: Такие вещи делаются не аллокаторами, а теми, кто работает с памятью. Т.е. на более высоком уровне.



Пишите класс, который будет просить у аллокатора несколько кусков, а наружу предоставлять интерфейс как будто кусок сплошной. Или используйте "гениальные" указатели - через них можно реализовать прозрачное перемещение уже выделенных кусков. Или аллокатор, который будет так работать, что при Вашей стратегии использования фрагментация будет небольшой...

Comment: @Михаил М, а почему аллокаторами не делаются? Геморно?

Comment: @SoloMio, это вводит дополнительный уровень косвенности и, потому, замедление. Вот виртуальная память поддерживается железом, поэтому там без потери скорости несколько последовательных для процесса страниц памяти могут отображаться на разбросанные физические страницы

Comment: @SoloMio: потому что ни одна программа не готова к тому, что элементы массива имеют адреса не подряд. Значит, эту логику надо включать в кастомный класс.

Comment: @SoloMio, если интересуетесь "массивом из кусочков", то возможно какие-то идеи из [этого старого вопроса](http://hashcode.ru/questions/16650) окажутся полезными.

Comment: @avp, а почему всякие std::vector и std::string принимают в качестве параметров шаблона allocator? уж не для таких ли нужд как у меня?

Comment: Именно для этого.